# Smooth shading in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to create ocean waves in libGDX following this paper:
http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Publications/2002/HNC02/wavesSCA.pdf.

Everything is working out but when i try to shade my triangle mesh using reflective shading, the shading is not smooth and very choppy. I am just passing vertex normals to the mesh and not the surface normals but I dont really know how to pass surface normals. Here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs2bw.jpg).

Below are my shaders:-

[vertexShader]

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform mat4 u_viewTrans;

varying vec3 pos_eye;
varying vec3 nor_eye;

void main() {
    pos_eye = vec3 (u_viewTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4 (a_position, 1.0));
    nor_eye = vec3 (u_viewTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4 (a_normal, 0.0));
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

[FragmentShader]

```
#ifdef GL_ES 
precision mediump float;
#endif


varying vec3 pos_eye;
varying vec3 nor_eye;
uniform samplerCube u_environmentCubemap;
uniform mat4 u_viewTrans;
uniform mat4 u_inverseViewTrans;

void main () {
  vec3 incident_eye = normalize (pos_eye);
  vec3 normal = normalize (nor_eye);

  vec3 reflected = reflect (incident_eye, normal);
  reflected = vec3 (u_inverseViewTrans * vec4 (reflected, 0.0));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(textureCube(u_environmentCubemap, reflected).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

I have spent much time to make the shading smooth , I have also tried using a framebuffer but I am not able to achieve the desired result. If someone could help me with smooth shading, it would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Calculate normals for each vertex as an average of the normals of all the adjacent triangles. That's the vertex normal you should be applying to the mesh.

Comment: That is what I am doing, for each of the vertex normals. and getting the result shown in screenshot. Is there any option in libgdx or glsl to interpolate the normal values between two vertices ? since i am just setting the vertex normals and not the surface normals

Comment: GLSL always interpolates normals between vertices. I'm not sure what you mean by surface normals.

Comment: Oh if thats the case then can you suggest what am I not implementing correctly since I am not getting a smooth shaded model.

Do I need to implement Phong shading or Gouraud shading to avoid these visible triangular shaded regions on my model ? And do I need to manualy implement phong or gouraud shading or is there an option in Libgdx or GLSL to do so ?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, my first guess is that really the problem is that your mesh is not tessellated enough for your wavelength. So I would try a bigger wavelength or more detailed mesh first.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 , bigger wavelength did solve most of my problems.
Its looking much smoother now. We can close this question now.